# looping a form in c#

Tags: c#, loops, input

How do I make it so at the end of this program it asks for another input so that the form resets and another form is made based on the new input?

```
 static void Main()
    {
        String totalsecondsstring;
        int totalseconds, hour, minutes, second;
        Console.WriteLine("How long did the race take (in seconds)?");
        totalsecondsstring = Console.ReadLine();
        totalseconds = Convert.ToInt32(totalsecondsstring);
        hour = totalseconds / 3600;
        minutes = (totalseconds - (hour * 3600)) / 60;
        second = (totalseconds - (hour * 3600)) - (minutes * 60);
        Console.Write("Runers Time\n");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------\n");
        Console.WriteLine("{0,-5} | {1,-5} | {2,-5} | {3,-5}", "Runner ", hour + " hours", minutes + " minutes", second + " seconds");
    }
```

Comment: Be careful when tossing around the word "Form" in programming. *Especially* .NET programming. That is not a form. Its a console app.

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

Use `while(true)` loop:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    while(true) {
        // Your code
    }
}
```

Call the `Main` method at the end of the `Main` method:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    // Your code
    Main();
}
```

I suggest you to use the first approach.

Comment: Use `Console.Clear()` :)

Comment: Recursively calling `Main` will eventually result in a `StackOverflowException`, so definitely don't do that.

Comment: I agree with @juharr. Even if it will take days for a user (may be even years) before that happen, it is better idea to use loop.

Comment: Also breaking the recursive loop would be messy as it would require you to do something like throwing an exception to stop it.

Comment: You should remove the recursive main solution, it's not a good idea

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example,

```
static void Main()
        {
            bool anotherRace;

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("How long did the race take (in seconds)?");
                string totalsecondsstring = Console.ReadLine();

                int totalseconds = Convert.ToInt32(totalsecondsstring);
                int hour = totalseconds / 3600;
                int minutes = (totalseconds - (hour * 3600)) / 60;
                int second = (totalseconds - (hour * 3600)) - (minutes * 60);

                Console.Write("Runers Time\n");
                Console.WriteLine("-----------\n");
                Console.WriteLine(
                    "{0,-5} | {1,-5} | {2,-5} | {3,-5}",
                    "Runner ",
                    hour + " hours",
                    minutes + " minutes",
                    second + " seconds");

                Console.WriteLine("Would you like to do another race? y or n\n");

                anotherRace = Console.ReadLine() == "y";
            }
            while (anotherRace);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use one of loops: `for`, `foreach`, `while`, or `do...while`. For more details I would recommend the following readings: [Looping Statements (C# vs Java)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228598(v=vs.90).aspx) or [C# - Loops](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_loops.htm)